# I want to add a constraint from one end of a truck to the end of a trailer

Tags: parent

I want to add a constraint from one end of a truck to the end of a trailer, but the constraint goes from the center of each object. I put a box on each end to use the constraint, but if these boxes are parented to the objects they are on the constraint goes from the middle of the objects.

So how do I make the constraint operate only from the boxes?

Comment: What kind of constraint? Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish. Can you add an illustration that describes what you are after?

Comment: Actually any constraint, as what I want is the action points to be at the end of the truck and the beginning of the trailer. To avoid moving the trucks pivot point causing centre of gravity problems, I tried to put a box on the end and connect from there to a box on the start of the trailer. If those boxes are parented to their respective objects the connection then goes to the truck and trailer and away from the boxes.

Comment: you can parent the truck and the box to empties and place them where you need them, then add constraints to the empties...

Comment: Yes that worked. I realised that the rigid constraints themselves were empties, although if one uses the property menu an actual object can take on the behaviour of the rigid contstraint without the need for an empty, which could be what I want as well. It will be great when they harmonise Blender generally with BGE physics!